# How to handle chromium microphone permission pop-ups in playwright?

Tags: python, e2e-testing, playwright

### What I'm trying to do

Test a website that requires microphone access with playwright

### The problem

Pop-up in question comes up and seems to ignore supposedly granted permissions. Permission can be given manually, but this seems against the spirit of automation.

[image]

### What I tried

```
with sync_playwright() as p:

    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    context = browser.new_context(permissions=['microphone'])
...
```

Granting permissions via context doesn't work for some reason. The permission pop-up still comes up.

I also tried to record a walkthrough with playwrights record script, but it's not recording granting microphone permissions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing some command line [flags](https://webrtc.github.io/webrtc-org/testing/) that tell chrome to simulate having a microphone. Give this sample a shot.

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright


def run(playwright):
    chromium = playwright.chromium
    browser = chromium.launch(headless=False, args=['--use-fake-device-for-media-stream', '--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream'])
    context = browser.new_context()
    context.grant_permissions(permissions=['microphone'])
    page = context.new_page()
    page.goto("https://permission.site/")
    page.click('#microphone')
    page.pause()
    # other actions...
    browser.close()


with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    run(playwright)
```

Comment: in case anyone wants to play an audio file via the fake mic: add `--use-file-for-fake-audio-capture=audio.wav` to the args list

Answer (score 1):

Anyone coming using JavaScript, this is how I was able to resolve the issue:

in playwright.config.ts (or playwright.config.js), in the defineConfig object, there should be a "use" object. you can add permissions there.

Here is my whole playwright.config.ts file:

```
import { defineConfig, devices } from '@playwright/test';

/**
 * See https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration.
 */
export default defineConfig({
  testDir: './src/__tests__/e2e',
  /* Run tests in files in parallel */
  fullyParallel: true,
  /* Fail the build on CI if you accidentally left test.only in the source code. */
  forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,
  /* Retry on CI only */
  retries: process.env.CI ? 2 : 0,
  /* Opt out of parallel tests on CI. */
  workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : undefined,
  /* Reporter to use. See https://playwright.dev/docs/test-reporters */
  reporter: 'html',
  /* Shared settings for all the projects below. See https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testoptions. */
  use: {
    /* Base URL to use in actions like `await page.goto('/')`. */
    baseURL: process.env.API_URL || 'http://localhost:3000',

    headless: true,
    viewport: { width: 1280, height: 720 },
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    permissions: ['camera', 'microphone'],
    screenshot: 'only-on-failure',
    trace: 'retain-on-failure',
    video: 'retain-on-failure',
  },

  /* Configure projects for major browsers */
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'chromium',
      use: {
        ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
        launchOptions: {
          args: [
            '--use-fake-device-for-media-stream',
            '--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream',
          ],
        },
      },
    },

    // {
    //   name: 'firefox',
    //   use: {
    //     ...devices['Desktop Firefox'],
    //     permissions: ['microphone', 'camera'],
    //   },
    // },

    /* Test against mobile viewports. */
    // {
    //   name: 'Mobile Chrome',
    //   use: { ...devices['Pixel 5'] },
    // },
    // {
    //   name: 'Mobile Safari',
    //   use: { ...devices['iPhone 12'] },
    // },

    /* Test against branded browsers. */
    // {
    //   name: 'Microsoft Edge',
    //   use: { ...devices['Desktop Edge'], channel: 'msedge' },
    // },
    // {
    //   name: 'Google Chrome',
    //   use: { ...devices['Desktop Chrome'], channel: 'chrome' },
    // },
  ],

  /* Run your local dev server before starting the tests */
  webServer: {
    command: 'yarn dev',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000',
    reuseExistingServer: !process.env.CI,
  },
});
```

The important part for here is the line `permissions: ['camera', 'microphone'],` in the use object as mentioned.